# for loop for my dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I wanted to make my df - dataframe to be updated inside for loop i am getting error like the following kindly help me out.

```
add_prob<-function()
ad<-as.integer(readline("Enter how many probables, you are going to add: 
"))
for (i in 1:ad) {
dt<-Sys.Date()
Reg<-format(dt,format="%d %B % %Y")
Na<-as.character(readline("Enter the participant Name: "))
Do<-as.character(readline("Enter the domain he is working: "))
Co<-as.integer(readline("Enter his mobile number: "))
E<-as.character(readline("Enter his E-mail ID: "))
# tnam<-paste0('Item:',i,sep='')
df[i, ]<-data.frame(Reg,Na,Do,Co,E)
names(df)=c("Date","Name","Domain","Mobile No.", "E-Mail ID")
}
print(newdf)
```

Comment: Can you indent properly your code ?

Comment: you can use `rbind` for appending new rows to a dataframe

Comment: And what happens if the user makes a mistake at E-mail ID? (S)he has to repeat the process all over again... Would reading the information from a plain text file or a spreadsheet work for your setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because there is no predefined object called `df` yet you are calling the object and you wand to sore the values in a specified position of the object which is not in existence. So maybe prior to running your code, define your object:

```
 ad<-as.integer(readline("Enter how many probables, you are going to add: "))
 df=data.frame(Reg=NA,Na=NA,Do=NA,Co=NA,E=NA)
 for (i in 1:ad) {
     dt<-Sys.Date()
     Reg<-format(dt,format="%d %B % %Y")
     Na<-as.character(readline("Enter the participant Name: "))
     Do<-as.character(readline("Enter the domain he is working: "))
     Co<-as.integer(readline("Enter his mobile number: "))
     E<-as.character(readline("Enter his E-mail ID: "))
     # tnam<-paste0('Item:',i,sep='')
     df<-rbind(df,data.frame(Reg,Na,Do,Co,E))
  }
 df=df[-1,]
 names(df)=c("Date","Name","Domain","Mobile No.", "E-Mail ID")
 print(df)
```

Comment: Enter the participant Name: kum
Enter the domain he is working: it
Enter his mobile number: 789
Enter his E-mail ID: m10
Enter the participant Name: art
Enter the domain he is working: rte
Enter his mobile number: 90887
Enter his E-mail ID: kums
> df
  Date Name Domain Mobile No. E-Mail ID
1    1    1      1          1         1
2    1    1      1          1         1